# Does React make any guarantees that the `props` object reference stays stable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently I saw code akin to the following contrived example:

```
const MyComp = props => {
  const [prevProps, setPrevProps] = useState(props)

  if (props !== prevProps) {
    setPrevProps(props);
    // do something else...
  }
}
```

The component uses some kind of derived state to remember the previous props. If the memory location of `props` has changed (`props !== prevProps`), it will sync the new props to `useState`.

Yeah, it doesn't make that much sense, but my point is: Does React make any guarantees, that the object reference of `props` stays the same, given no contained property of `props` has changed?

At least, this seems to be the case for the tests I have done. If a parent component changes any of the props, there will be a new `props` object created.

I would appreciate any official documentation link proving this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does React make any guarantees, that the object reference of props stays the same, given no contained property of props has changed?

**No, it doesn't.**

> If a parent component changes any of the props, there will be a new props object created.

If the parent re-renders, **the child will always receive its props in a new object**, even if nothing in it has changed.

If you want to prevent that, you will have to use 
`PureComponent` or [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) which will perform a shallow equal comparison of all the properties of the `props` object and prevent re-rendering if none of them changed.

```js
const { memo, useState, useEffect } = React;

const Child = props => {
  // only gets called when `props` changes
  useEffect(() => console.log(props.name, ": props changed"), [props]); 

  return <p>{props.name}: {props.text}</p>;
};

const MemoChild = memo(Child);

const Parent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [text, setText] = useState("foo");
  const handleTextChange = event => setText(event.target.value);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>
        Click to force Re-Render
      </button>
      <input id="text" value={text} onChange={handleTextChange} />
      <Child name="Child without memo()" text={text} />
      <MemoChild name="Child with memo()" text={text} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Have a look at this example. You will see that when you press the button, the child not using `memo` will re-render, even if the props `name` or `text` have not changed. It will still receive a new `props` object.

But when you enter something into the input, both components re-render, because the `text` property of the props changed.

It should also be noted that this is only a performance optimization. You should not rely on `memo` preventing a re-render at all times.

> This method only exists as a [*performance optimization*](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html). Do not rely on
>   it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful (+1)! I also found the mistake in my tests: I always triggered a re-render from the child, so the `props` references was kept the same. If I force a render in the *parent*, as you say, there will be a new `props` object. So you nailed it pretty much down already. Just in case, someone finds something from the official docs, I'll wait with the accept.

Comment: @bela53 As far as I know, it's not explicitly mentioned anywhere in the docs. If you look at what jsx compiles to you will also see that it results in calls like `React.createElement(Child, {name: "Child without memo()", text: text})` where the second argument is always a new object composed of the props. This is what gets called in the parent when the child component renders. So assuming that react does not internally compare that new object with the old one to discard it in case of equality it's logical to assume it will be a different object on every render triggered by the parent.

Comment: Yeah, this analogy makes perfect sense to me and also explains, why the `props` reference didn't change with only the child re-rendering. Only if parent `render` is re-triggered, it would invoke `React.createElement(Child, {...})` with a new `props` object as 2nd argument. Thanks