# useEffect multiple dependencies - what is causing multiple renders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So in my code below, I want to understand what is causing the component to re-render multiple times. Even though most of the time this code runs without any problem, but sometimes it causes the browser to become unresponsive.

I can't pinpoint what is causing that problem and believe that relooking at the useEffect might be the key to solving it.

Because the **dispatch, props & addToast** are dependent on **success**, should I remove them from the dependency array and just keep success and error?

Is there a way to figure out which dependency to keep and which to remove?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_RESET });
      dispatch(listProducts());
      props.onHide();
      addToast("Product has been added!", {
        appearance: "success",
        autoDismiss: false,
      });
    } else if (error) {
      addToast(error, { appearance: "error", autoDismiss: false });
    }
  }, [dispatch, success, error, addToast, props]);
```

Comment: Remove `props` and pass `onHide` directly. `props` is a new object on each render.

Comment: @OriDrori  am using props.onHide() because the useEffect is being used in a Modal component.  I can't remove it until I have deconstructed it in the component, right?

Comment: Remove dependencies one by one and know which one is causing the issue, seems props is causing it.

Comment: @RitikBanger the browser becomes unresponsive at random times thus, it is hard to recreate the error one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moving [comment from @Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73801166/useeffect-multiple-dependencies-what-is-causing-multiple-renders#comment130315965_73801166) into answer.*

---

> [...] If the parent re-renders, the child will always receive it's `props` in a new object, even if nothing in it has changed. [...]
>
> Source: ["Does React make any guarantees that the `props` object reference stays stable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60654949/8746648)

The problem you are observing is likely the cause of `dispatch` triggering the parent component to re-render which then creates a new `props` object and thus re-renders your component.  This is an infinite feedback loop.

You can avoid this issue by removing `props` from the dependency list and instead add `props.onHide`.  This alone may not be enough because the identity of `props.onHide` could change if it is defined as a plain function within the parent component.

You may have to use `useCallback` in the parent component to ensure that the identity of the function is stable, otherwise, you could encounter the same issue.

---

You can also remove `dispatch` from the list of dependencies, because react guarantees that it doesn't change between renders:

> React guarantees that `dispatch` function identity is stable and won't change on re-renders. This is why it's safe to omit from the `useEffect` or `useCallback` dependency list.
>
> Source: ["Hooks API Reference"](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

---

To summarize, your dependency list would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // ...
}, [success, error, addToast, props.onHide]);
```

(There is also this mysterious `listProducts` function if that is defined within the component you may have to add it as dependency as well.)

And in the parent component you may have to use `useCallback` when you define the `onHide` function:

```
// The child component could cause this component to re-render creating a 
// feedback loop.  The 'useCallback' prevents the identity of 'onHide' from 
// changing thus breaking the loop.
let onHide = useCallback(() => {
    // ...
}, [/* ... */]);

// ...

<Foo onHide={onHide} />
```

---

*Since that apparently helped, I am moving this from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73801166/useeffect-multiple-dependencies-what-is-causing-multiple-renders/73801647#comment130317845_73801647) into the answer:*

[This article briefly touches the whole `useCallback` thing, that helped me understand it.](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: `<UserModal show={userModalShow} onHide={() => setUserModalShow(false)} />` This is how the onHide props is being used in the parent component. How should I use this with useCallback?

Comment: `let onHide = useCallback(() => setUserModalShow(false), []);` and then `<UserModal onHide={onHide} />`.

Comment: [This article briefly touches the whole `useCallback` thing, that helped me understand it.](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: Thank you! That article is really helpful! listProducts function is actually a redux import so it is not defined within the component and I don't believe that it needs to be added as a dependency.